# Does DB2 preserve the order of data in INSERT?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a query like this

```
INSERT INTO A(A_UID,A_INT) SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR A_SEQUENCE, Integer FROM 
( SELECT DISTINCT X .... ORDER BY Y ) ALIAS;
```

question is does the data in table A ordered by Y?
I don't read the whole table to sort it, I read the first N number of UID each time and for my business logic to work it need to be sorted by Y!

Should I redesign the whole thing? :(((

Comment: You asked this already, and got the same answers in the comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124090/sort-insert-into-with-sequence-and-distinct).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data in a relational database table is *never* intrinsically ordered. 
Regardless of how you fill the table. 
You must always use `ORDER BY` when `SELECT`ing if you expect to get some specific order of rows.

Comment: Data may not be, but it has to assign a UID to it from sequence, I use this UID to get the order. question is when it INSERT does it keep the order???

Comment: @Mars, when you INSERT, DB2 of course keeps the order from SELECT. So it assigns the first value from the sequence to the lowest-Y value, the second sequence value to the second-lowest-Y value, and so on.

Comment: @Mars There is no guarantee that it will retain any order.  How a DBMS decides where to store a row – at the end of a page, in the middle, on a new page, etc. depends on lots of variables.  If you want *guaranteed* order, use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @lan bjorjovde If you look at the Insert SQL above, it has a sequence. I don't care where DBMS store the data, cause by the UID assigned by Sequence I can have the order and that is what I care about.

Comment: @AlexShesterov Thanks Alex, the comment was the answer I was looking for.